# is there a HTML javascript library for editing images?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I'm looking for a client-side HTML library (javascript) -- I need to allow a user to draw on a TIFF or JPG image.
I don't think I've even seen a web site that allows image editing (w/o an add-in).
The alternative would probably be Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Try pixastic. Link is [here](http://www.pixastic.com/).

Comment: pixastic is impressive.  Unfortunately, I have no control over browsers, but mainly, I need line and text drawing functions.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [**fabricjs**](http://fabricjs.com/) , **[pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)**. take a look at it.

You can crop image with [**jcrop**](http://mrbool.com/jquery-crop-cropping-images-with-jcrop/26243)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little jQuery plug-in built on top of Pixastic: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/AndreasLagerkvist/Files/pixastic-editor/. More info about the plug-in can be found here: http://exscale.se/archives/jquery/#article-240